# Failed Elasticsearch 7.3 Install on MAC El Capitan. Repeated installation failure due to problems enabling bootstrap memory locking

Tags: elasticsearch, installation

Good Evening Everyone,

I have been trying to install a single stand alone instance (locally) of Elasticsearch 7.3 on my MAC Book Pro El Capitan (10.11.6, 4GB-Ram). I really thought this would be fairly straight forward but alas ES is having memory locking issues whilst being installed on my mac.

Details:

1. I downloaded, and have been attempting to install, Elasticsearch 7.3. It was downloaded from here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-install.html
2. After extracting the archive I proceeded to follow instructions for installation, starting with running the binary executable - "./elasticsearch" - by running this command -->
   ***cd elasticsearch-7.3.0/bin
   ./elasticsearch***
3. Upon running said command I have repeatedly been getting this error -->

   ***"[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/endFc.png) bootstrap checks failed [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/endFc.png): memory locking requested for elasticsearch process but memory is not locked"***
4. After conducting some research, I now realize that Elasticsearch is basically having problems enabling 'memory locking'. It is fully understood that elasticsearch does not like memory swapping and that "memory locking" needs to be enabled using the --> ***bootstrap.memory_lock: true*** command, however it seems to me that I have a case here, where this setting is being passed to Elasticsearch but Elasticsearch is not able to read said setting to lock memory (Java Heap) and complete the installation of my ES instance.
5. I have tried everything to try to enable "memory locking", to no avail. I have set the following config parameters in the following files:

   A) I added the following lines to **/etc/security/limits.conf** file:

   ```
      elasticsearch soft memlock unlimited
      elasticsearch hard memlock unlimited

      * - memlock unlimited
      * - nofile 100000
      * - nproc 32768
      * - as unlimited
   ```

   B)  I added the following lines to the **jvm.options** file:

   ```
     -Xms2g  (initial size of total heap space, set to half of RAM)  
     -Xmx2g  (maximum size of heap space, set to half of RAM)  
     -Des.enforce.bootstrap.checks=true (enforcing memory locking checks)  
     -Djna.tmpdir=chosenpath/elasticsearch-7.3.0/tmp (this seemed important)
   ```

   C)  I edited the following lines in the **elasticsearch.yml** file:

   ```
     bootstrap.memory_lock: true   
     network.host: 0.0.0.0  
     http.port: 9200
   ```

   D)  I added the **'/etc/launchd.conf'** file (in trying to increase my max processes and max files available) and added the following lines:

   ```
     limit maxproc 2048 2048  
     limit maxfiles 1024 unlimited
   ```

   E)  I added the **'/etc/sysctl.conf'** file (in trying to increase my max processes, and max processes available per user) and added the following lines:

   ```
     # Turn up maxproc  
     kern.maxproc=2048 

     # Turn up the maxproc per user  
     kern.maxprocperuid=1024

     # Remove core files  
     kern.coredump=0
   ```

   F) My **ulimit -as** output has remained unchanged no matter what I do, and still gives me the following output:

   ```
   core file size           (blocks, -c) 0  
   data seg size          (kbytes, -d) unlimited  
   file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited  
   max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited  
   max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited  
   open files                     (-n) 256  
   pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1  
   stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192  
   cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited  
   max user processes              (-u) 709  
   virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
   ```
6. But no matter what I try, I always get theses 2 errors:

   A) *"Unable to lock JVM Memory: error=78, reason=Function not implemented"*

   B) *"ERROR: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/endFc.png) bootstrap checks failed [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/endFc.png): memory locking requested for elasticsearch process but memory is not locked"*
7. I have looked into maybe disabling memory swapping entirely on my mac, but decided that maybe that was too drastic an action, and would prefer that feature (memory locks, no swapping) to be invoked only when my ES is active. I also cannot seem to find anywhere where one can set LimitMEMLOCK=infinity because it seems that the concept of elasticsearch.service dose not exist as a part of installing ES on a MAC.

I thought installing ES would be as simple as editing the "Elasticsearch.yml" and "jvm.options" file and that would be it. Boy was I wrong.

I would love your assistance guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are the current contents of my "limits.conf" file:                                                                                                                                      
    
    elasticsearch soft memlock unlimited
    elasticsearch hard memlock unlimited

    * - memlock unlimited
    * - nofile 100000
    * - nproc 32768
    * - as unlimited.

Still when I reboot, my "open files" and "max user processes" parameters remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

So - I finally got ES 7.3 to install on my MAC (El Capitan).

I removed this entry from my jvm.options file:

```
-Des.enforce.bootstrap.checks=true
```

Somehow this did not cause ES to crap out when authenticating memory locking. Removing this parameter disables ES's ability to enforce bootstrap checks, even if "bootstrap.memory_lock: true" in elasticsearch.yml config file. Now all I have to figure out is how to add 2 additional nodes to this same ES instance, without getting this error:

```
uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: BindTransportException[Failed to bind to 
[9300]]; nested: BindException[Address already in use]
```

Seems like i need to make some adjustments to my elasticsearch.yml file. current pertinent settings here:

```
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
transport.host: localhost
#transport.tcp.port: 9300-9400 (commented out for now)
#node.master: true             (commented out for now)
#node.data: true               (commented out for now)
#discovery.type: single-node
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
```

Anyone have any ideas?